# Sublime Text 3 - jQuery snippet with $ not working

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext3

I wrote that little snippet to help my workflow in Sublime Text 3:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    (function ($) {"use strict";$(function () {$1});}(jQuery));
]]></content>
    Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet
    <tabTrigger>self.function</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>self.trigger.function</description>
</snippet>
```

The contextual menu display is when I start to type "self" in a javascript file, but when I hit "Enter", nothing is pasted to my file.

Any idea why that is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `$` if you want that character to appear literally. Or else SublimeText would assume it to be a Variable field. So just do this -

```
(function (\$) {"use strict";\$(function () {$1});}(jQuery));
```

Now it'll work. Details are under the [`content` section of the documentation](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html#snippets-file-format).